# Has the Java language maintained source-code backward compatibility throughout its history?

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility

Has Java always maintained source-code backward compatibility during its development?

More precisely: given two Java versions X and Y with X < Y, is any program for Java X also a valid program for Java Y, with the same semantics?
E.g. X = Java 2 (or 1.2 with the old numbering) and Y = Java 5.

Or is there only compatibility at the JVM level: e.g. a class compiled for the JVM 1.2 can be run by the JVM 5?

If it is possible to run Java 2 code on a Java 5 (or 6, or 7), what are the exact steps that I have to follow? Compile directly with a Java 5 compiler? Compile with a Java 2 compiler and run on JVM 5?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I was a bit unsure as to which one I should accept, because several answers were informative. I had to pick one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sun, and now Oracle, have always been extremely careful with backward compatibility with regards to Java.

**Binary compatibility**: You should be able to run Java code compiled with older versions on newer versions without modification. There might, however, be small incompatibilities.

**Source compatibility**: Code originally written for an older JDK version should almost always compile without modification with a newer Java compiler, but there are a number of small incompatibilities. One of them is the `enum` keyword added in Java 5; on older versions of Java, `enum` was a valid identifier, but not on Java 5. Also, importing classes from the default package has been removed (I think since Java 1.4). So you can't do:

```
import SomeClassName;
```

anymore on Java 1.4 or newer.

In the documentation of every JDK release there is a document about backward compatibility with previous releases, which lists the details.

- [Java SE 7 and JDK 7 Compatibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html)
- [Java SE 6 Compatibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html)
- [Incompatibilities in J2SE 5.0 (since 1.4.2)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137462.html)
- [Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition Version 1.4.0 Compatibility with Previous Releases](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-j2se1-141394.html)

Answer (score 4):

Starting witg Java 1.5 `enum` became a reserved word. Thus any Java 1.4 source code containing `enum` became broken starting with 1.5

Comment: The same thing happened to `assert` in 1.4. There are probably other examples too.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know JVMs are backwards compatible.  A class compiled with JDK 1 will work in the latest JRE 7.
The libraires are definitely not 100% compatible.  Some methods have been deprecated (and subsequently removed).  Some classes changed behavior in (usually) subtle ways which will cause programs to behave differently.

Comment: Is there anything that's been completely removed?  I know they like to deprecate stuff, but i can't think of anything that's actually been taken out.

Comment: Yes :) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#getDescent() In JDK 1 and perhaps 1.1 this method was by mistake called "getDecent".  It was then deprecated and eventually removed :)

Comment: (come to think of it, I didn't verify that it is removed, perhaps it is still there...)

Comment: 1.7 docs still list it.  Deprecated, of course, but still there.  :)

Comment: Nope my 1.7 install still has it - which really shows how utterly useless the deprecation feature is apart as a  "There's a new better method over there" annotation. Fun trivia though :D

Comment: @Voo - how does that make the deprecation feature itself useless?  not removing it is a decision made by Sun, completely orthogonal to the deprecation feature.

Comment: @jtahlborn Well the deprecation process should ultimately lead to removing old methods. Considering that we can't even remove a wrongly named function that was replaced in 1.1 I think the argument that we will ever replace anything in the JDK is pretty weak. Hence the whole deprecation process is useless - a simple annotation "Newer, better version over there" would have the same effect.

Comment: Meh.  The JDK's decided to maintain backwards compatibility for all time; it'll never delete anything, but at least deprecated methods won't get used as much in new code.

Comment: @Voo - just because Sun/Oracle uses it that way doesn't mean _you_ have to.  your argument only holds in the context of the jdk API.

Comment: @jtahlborn Ah that's what you mean. I wholeheartedly agree, it was never meant as anything but a comment about the deprecation in the JDK.

Comment: @Voo - in the context of the jdk, i definitely agree.  kind of hoping they'd take a major release and just rip out all the cruft.

Comment: I think the craft that is worth ripping out (like the entire java.util.Date ;) is absolutely impossible to rip out.  And small things like getMaxDecent are not worth the trouble.

Comment: Maybe if there's ever a Java 2.0, stuff like that will not be in it.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can always run with a newer version of the JDK then the one used for compilation. The other way around is not possible (unless you compile using the `-target` parameter).

You might want to read [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) (in particular the *Cross-Compilation Options* section), which explains the target parameter and the default behavior

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the backward compatibility analysis of the Java (Jre) library classes here: http://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/timeline/jre/

The report is generated by the *[japi-compliance-checker](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker)* tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Java is generally compatible with previous releases but anyway it may be a lot f issues with migration.
See my article about [migration from JDK 6 to 8](https://stokito.wordpress.com/2015/07/28/linkset-migration-to-java-8/) for details